# iOS 10 UIDocumentInteractionController PDF Preview Very Slow to Display and Dismiss

Tags: ios, pdf, uidocumentinteraction

I am using a `UIDocumentInteractionController` to preview small PDF files (approx 83K).  I noticed on `iOS10` when calling `presentPreviewAnimated` that the preview takes a very long time to load the document (5+ seconds).  While loading, a blank white screen is displayed.

Then, when clicking `Done`,  there is another pause of ~5s where the app becomes completely unresponsive (can't scroll or tap done again), followed by the dismissal of the preview.  Has anyone else noticed this issue? If so, have you found any way to resolve it?